# Studying the convergence of $\sum_1^\infty \frac{(\beta n )^n}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\sum_1^\infty \frac{(\beta n )^n}{n!}$ I've applied

$$\frac{1}{R}= \lim_{n\to\infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$$

Where R is the radius of convergence. Answer I got:

Converges for $-e^{-1}<\beta< e^{-1}$

How would I test the convergence for endpoints though? $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{n!}= \infty$$ Clearly $\beta = - e^{-1}$ won't work since the coefficient is not monotonically decreasing (above) How to test $e^{-1}$ though?

Comment: @myglasses It's not a duplicate.  The OP is asking about the convergence at the endpoints of the interval of convergence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Stirling's formula, we have

$$n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne \right)^n$$

as $n\to \infty$.

Hence we see that $\frac{n^n}{e^n\,n!}\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$.

By the comparison test, the series diverges for $\beta =1/e$. If Leibniz's alternating series test applies, the series converges for $\beta =-1/e$.

Leibniz's alternating series test requires that the summand $a_n=\frac{n^n}{e^n\,n!}$ is monotonically decreasing. To check this condition, we write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}&=\left(\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{e^{n+1}(n+1)!}\right)\left(\frac{e^n n!}{n^n}\right)\\\\
&=\frac1e \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\\\\
&<1
\end{align}$$

Hence $a_{n+1}<a_n$ for all $n$ and the summand decreases monotonically, which proves that the series indeed converges for $\beta =-1/e$.

Comment: @Did Didier, I've edited.  Thank you for the suggestion.  -Mark

Comment: @Did Thank you!  Much appreciative.